# Content flow under page

Tags: html, css

I do not know how to properly put this in in a question but is there a way that a wrapper div floats under the page meaning that it will start right as the media screen ends at the bottom no matter how much blank space is left?

For example,

```
<div class="wrapper 1">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>A text of something interesting</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper-2"> <!-- This DIV needs to start right under the media screen -->
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>A text of something interesting</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the question: what do you mean by "media screen" and what's wrong with your code snippet? Thanks and regards,

Comment: Do you want to place "wrapper-2" to the bottom of the page?

Comment: @AlexBell isn't any screen, monitor called a media screen? If not, excuse me.

Comment: @seva.rubbo Yes. But as there are different sized screens I wanted to know is there a way that the content is being placed right under the page regardless the height

Comment: So you want `wrapper-2` to be at the bottom of the web page no matter what? `position:absolute;bottom:0;` in CSS would do that.

Comment: I was confused by "DIV to start under the media screen": how any part of content suppose to go out of screen? Probably you are talking about CSS overflow properties (clipping the content), or position: absolute/fix, which may be used to place the element at the bottom regardless of screen height. Also, keep in mind that monitor's active screen height could be different from page height because of space taken by toolbars, taskbar, menu bars, etc.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Maybe you need to post your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to have your `wrapper-2` element at the bottom of a webpage regardless of how thin your content is, you can consider the following:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="wrapper-1">header</div>
    <div id="main">main content</div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper-2">footer</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 5000px; /* obscene number strictly for your visual convenience */
}
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
}
#main {
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
}
 #wrapper-2 {
    position: relative;
    clear:both;
}
/*Opera Fix*/
 body:before {
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:0;
    margin-top:-32767px;
}
```

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1wj1fvqr/)

More can be found on the above example [here](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html)

However, if you're just looking for a simple sticky-footer:

```
<div id="wrapper-2">footer</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
body { overflow-x:hidden; }

#wrapper-2 {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[Simple sticky-footer Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1wj1fvqr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If I interpreted your question correctly, you want to hide the second div just underneath the viewport.

Make the div `position: absolute` and `top: 100%`. This will push the div just outside the visible area; it can then be scrolled to.

Note: Currently, if the content spills past the viewable area, it will overlap the second div. Unsure if this is a problem for what you are trying to achieve.

```css
.wrapper-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper 1">
  <h1>The Second div is hidden, SCROLL!</h1>
  <p>The Second div is hidden, SCROLL</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper-2">
  <!-- This DIV needs to start right under the media screen -->
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>A text of something interesting</p>
</div>
```